# How to connect python socket client side to server socket with url?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a client to connect to a server with given url address.

I used this way

```
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('HOST_NAME')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
sock.connect((host_ip, 8080))
```

but it printed the following error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Can someone explain me why is wrong and give me a solution?

Comment: Why are you `bind`ing the socket? This is used if _you_ are the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to `bind` your socket, this is done server-side.

Here's the example code from the [documentation for `socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) :

```
import socket

HOST = 'your-url.net'    # The remote host
PORT = 8080              # The same port as used by the server
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))
```

This is a simple snippet, which connects to the server, sends some data, and prints the response.